Do we need app registration in azure seperately even if I am using managed identity for my application?
I am trying to eliminate the need to secrets in my web applications. I am using managed identities for the same reason. But I have app registrations for all my web services for which I have managed identities. But I can also create standalone identities and use them for athorization, right?
Do I need app registration? Or am I missing something?
I want some document references and theoretical evidence as to when or why app registration is needed when I am already using managed identities.

Do you also have authentication enabled using App Service Auth/Easy Auth (this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) - doing so could result in you having app registrations with the same name as the web apps, if you just accept the values that setup gives you as given.
To answer your question, no, a managed identity does not generate an app registration that you can manage; it is only an enterprise app.
